# Mocking redis in python

Tags: python, testing, redis, mocking

I am trying to mock redis to enable testing of my python app which is built in Django. All of my instances of redis come from a module named record, with the **init**.py file containing:

```
redis_client = redis.from_url(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
```

I tried to patch the instance with [mockredis](https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis), but it is not working. Here is mode code:

```
class TestReleaseDashboard(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        # patch redis
        redis_patcher = patch('record.redis_client', mock_redis_client())
        self.redis = redis_patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(redis_patcher.stop)

        # add data
        self.redis.set('LATEST_UPDATE', 'Fall 2012')
        self.redis.set('NEXT_UPDATE', 'Spring 2013')

    def test_can_filter_pensions(self):
        print(redis_client)
        print(self.redis)
```

The result of those two print statements is:

```
Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
<mockredis.client.MockRedis object at 0x1132924d0>
```

What can I do to fix this and mock the instance?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the same problem, that is how I mocked my `redis` instance.
Hopes it helps someone. Given the code from the original question, use:

```
import fakeredis

@patch("redis_instance", fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis())
def test_can_filter_pensions(self):
    print(redis_client)
```

Result:

```
FakeStrictRedis<ConnectionPool<FakeConnection<server=<fakeredis._server.FakeServer object at 0x7fe87eb99410>,db=0>>>
```

Comment: How to get the "host" of this fakeredis ?

Comment: You can supply the connection parameters to it. It will create a FakeServer for every unique connection parameters. Keep in mind it is in memory implementation and not really connecting to other hosts.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using mockredispy and that isn't supported anymore :(
https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis

I would take a look at fakeredis:
https://pypi.org/project/fakeredis/

Comment: https://birdisle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html also implements the entire list of commands for redis