# Programmatically adding commands to `fakeredis` in Python

Tags: python, redis, mocking, fakeredis

Is there a way to programmatically add commands to [`fakeredis`](https://fakeredis.readthedocs.io)?

Unless I'm missing something, the [docs](https://fakeredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/implement-command/#implementing-support-for-a-command) suggest directly modifying library code (`FakeSocket` in `_fakesocket.py`), which I wish to avoid.

Motivation:
I'm writing some unittests for an application which uses [Redis-OM](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python). My models are `JsonModel`s, which cannot be instantiated without an active redis connection (their `__init__` method checks that the Redis server supports Json).
I'm trying to work around this limitation by using `FakeStrictRedis`. Unfortunately, it does not support the *COMMAND INFO* command which is used by `JsonModel`.

Related questions:

- [How to test a JSONModel in a unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578825/how-to-test-a-jsonmodel-in-a-unittest)
- [Mocking redis in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464725/mocking-redis-in-python)

Comment: pip install fakeredis[json]  ## Support for RedisJSON commands ?

Comment: @Mate - yes, I've installed the correct package. The problem is that `fakeredis` does not support 'command info', which is called by `JsonModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fakeredis supports the [RedisJson commands](https://fakeredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/redis-commands/RedisJson/).
You need to install it using the optional json flag.

```
pip install fakeredis[json]
```

The `COMMAND INFO` command is not implemented. You can open an issue describing the need and I'll see if I can implement it.

If you wish to implement it and contribute it to the next version, that would be great!

Comment: FYI: Support for `command info` was added in 2.20.0